# Insert specified values in R grouped df and fill up missing values using another df (R)

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dplyr, interpolation

I have 2 dfs : **df** & **xdf**.

```
df <- tibble(id = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b"),
             x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
             y = c(0.2, 0, 0.9, 7, 1, 0.3, 5, 5.1))

xdf <- tibble(id = c("a", "b"),
              x = c(2, 3.5))
```

In **df**, within "id" column, for the groups (a & b), I would like to insert only that row of **xdf** which matches the same id name as in df. How can I make it ? I have tried following commands but all of the values of xdf$x are inserted for each group.

```
ndf <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  do(add_row(., id = .$id[1], x = xdf$x))

> ndf
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
   id        x     y
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 a       1     0.2
 2 a       2     0  
 3 a       3     0.9
 4 a       4     7  
 5 a       2    NA  
 6 a       3.5  NA  
 7 b       1     1  
 8 b       2     0.3
 9 b       3     5  
10 b       4     5.1
11 b       2    NA  
12 b       3.5  NA

# expected result should be : ndf <- ndf[c(-6,-11),]
```

My end goal is to fill these newborns **NA** of ndf with the approx() function. But my issue remains because I'm using **xout = xdf$x** that calls supernumerary values. How can I overcome this? Can you help to write a function that makes **xout** varies?

```
f <- function(z) 
{
  fdf <- approx(z$x, z$y, xout = xdf$x, method = "linear")
  return(data.frame(nx= fdf$x, y.out = fdf$y, id = unique(z$id)))
}

jdf <- as.data.frame(ddply(ndf, .(id),  f))
zdf <- subset(jdf, select = c(id, nx, y.out))

> zdf
  id  nx y.out
1  a 2.0  0.00
2  a 3.5  3.95
3  b 2.0  0.30
4  b 3.5  5.05

# expected results
  id  nx y.out
1  a 2.0  0.00
2  b 3.5  5.05
```

Any helpful tips to this is welcome. Many thanks!

Comment: are you looking for `bind_rows(df, xdf)`? At least in your case this would produce your desired output.

Comment: ```bind_rows(df, xdf)``` is not what I am looking for since ```dim(zdf)``` remains 4*3. I want one output value in zdf, for one input value in ndf. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you add an example where the desired output is not the same as using bind_rows?

Comment: ```ndf <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  do(add_row(., id = .$id[1], x = xdf$x))``` gives ```dim(ndf)``` 12*3. ```bind_rows(df, xdf)``` gives a tibble of dim 10*3. Actually, ```dim(ndf)``` of 10*3 is what I want. Your answer is right. But I end up with ```zdf``` too large. I would like a unique value ```y.out``` for an unique input value ```a <- 2``` or ```b <- 3.5```. I know, it's not as easy as it sounds. Thank you.

Comment: and how is this unique `y.out` defined?

Comment: ```y.out``` is not really unique and that's my ultimate problem. I ask an unique ```y.out``` with a "not really unique" input ```x``` ie ```x.out``` (see approx()).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205732/discussion-between-cettt-and-user12409404-rm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(id = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b"),
             x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
             y = c(0.2, 0, 0.9, 7, 1, 0.3, 5, 5.1))

xdf <- tibble(id = c("a", "b"),
              x = c(2, 3.5))

ndf <- df %>%
  bind_rows(xdf) %>% 
  arrange(id)

zdf <- ndf %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
    group_modify(~mutate(., y_approx = approx(.$x, .$y, .$x, method = "linear")[["y"]])) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
  filter(is.na(y)) %>%
  select(id, y_approx)
```

Comment: This example ads one row to `ndf` for each row in `xdf`. If this isn't right, what would you want the dimensions of `ndf` to be given these dimensions of `ndf` and `xdf`?

Comment: ```dim(df) # 8*3
dim(xdf) # 2*2
dim(ndf) # 10*3``` This is right, I agree, the problem is a step further. I still ending up with ```dim(zdf)``` of 4*3. I would prefer a ```dim(zdf)``` exactly equal to 2*2. (my real data is much bigger than this exeample so I end up with too many unwanted values in ```zdf```). Merci.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I've now added the interpolation using `approx()`.

Comment: This proposal is not entirely correct but it is a good start to the answer I was looking for... It seems like your ```y_approx``` is directly interpolating within the whole vector ```ndf$y``` ...regardless of existing factors ```a``` and ```b``` : reason why our ```y.out```(s) are actually wrong.```y.out``` of ```a``` should be equal to ```0.``` and ```y.out``` of ```b``` should be equal to ```5.05``` (with a correct linear interpolation). ```ndf <- as.data.frame(ndf)``` and ```ndf$id <- as.factor(ndf$id)``` ```str(ndf)``` before your code leads to the same wrong ```y.out``` values. Thanks.

Comment: I found a neat function `group_modify()` which allows us to apply the interpolation function by id while staying within dplyr syntax.

Comment: Ok, that's perfect, you made it, thank you so much!